# Apache airflow REST API call fails with 403 forbidden when API authentication is enabled

Tags: airflow

Apache Airflow REST API fails with 403 forbidden for the call:

"/api/experimental/test"

**Configuration in airflow.cfg**

[webserver]

- authenticate = True
- auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth

[api]

- rbac = True
- auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth

After setting all this, docker image is built and run as a docker container.

Created the airflow user as follows:

```
airflow create_user -r Admin -u admin -e admin@hpe.com -f Administrator -l 1 -p admin
```

**Login with credentials for Web UI works fine.**

Where as login to REST API is not working.
HTTP Header for authentication:
Authorization BASIC YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

**Airflow version**: 1.10.9

Answer (score 8):

By creating user in the following manner we can access the Airflow experimental API using credentials.

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'new_user_name'
user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
user.password = 'set_the_password'
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

By creating user with "airflow create_user" command, we cannot access the Airflow Experimental APIs.

Comment: snippet works like a charm :)  Seems like web-server and api user entities are a different things. This should be better documented I spend few hours to figure out this :(

Comment: This works. Ty for this code snippet. I spent many weeks for this fix.